# Converting from factor to numeric without losing any decimal in R

Tags: r

I know similar questions have been asked before, however I cannot find a way to convert a factor to numeric without losing any of the decimals.

Here a brief example:

My vector looks like this:

```
january$pickup_latitude[1] = 40.751231
```

after doing:

```
as.numeric(as.character(january$pickup_latitude))
```

the result is:

```
january$pickup_latitude[1] = 40.75123
```

Is there any way in which I can preserve all the decimals even though each case has a different length?

Comment: First, see what `print(as.numeric(as.character(january$pickup_latitude)), digits=15)` looks like.

Comment: R doesn't print all decimals places by default. Look at `dput(january$pickup_latitude[1])`. Also be sure you are aware of how [floating point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) arithmetic works in general in R. If you need to keep digits exactly, then a factor/character is not a bad solution.

Comment: In other words, you didn't lose any precision, if I am following @MrFlick and HongOoi correctly.

Comment: Correct. You don't lose any precision, but not all digits show on the screen, unless you specify them in the way Hong Ooi shows.